# Java Webstart with parameters

Tags: java, parameters, applet, initialization, java-web-start

Can I launch a **Java WebStart** application with a set of parameters just like an applet is configured with the <param> tags ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah you can, the following shows an example:

```
<application-desc main-class="my.main.class">
    <argument>-user=bob</argument>
    <argument>-pass=8jkaiuasu</argument>
</application>
```

Showing you passing the arguments "-user=bob" and "-pass=8jkaiuasu" to the application.  Arguments are picked up in the standard way.

Comment: I think editing jnlp is a static solution, I mean imagine a web form where the user enter parameters before launching, Would the server need to write a jnlp file for every user click? it seems that there should be a better way

Comment: @HernánEche in this cause you use a servlet or other server side script to replace the values in the jnlp as it is serving the jnlp filefile

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check out the [JNLP Tag reference](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/ref.html)