# How to start Java GUI program conveniently for the end user

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, deployment, cmd

The user wants to start the Java GUI application from *Windows*, with some amount of additional JVM parameters.
For instance:

```
javaw -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -jar MyGUI.jar
```

If I add the above line to the batch file, the user can double-click the batch-file name.
And it's cool.  But there is one annoying side effect: **the batch file opens the *cmd* window before starting the GUI**.

Is there a **simple** way to start the java GUI application by double-clicking the batch-file (or some other file which suits the above needs) without opening the *cmd* window?

Comment: @chance Poor advice. You haven't understood my question.

Comment: Won't it launch your GUI without cmd window if you double click the shortcut to javaw? Or it is impossible to create shorcut for customers?

Comment: I mean you don't need the batch file at all. Just put the parameters in shorcut.

Comment: @It's clear to me now. You should state this from the beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see a number of ways:

- Use a launcher as generated by [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)  (thanks to CodeBrickie for the tip) or [Install4J/Exe4J](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html). Launch4J allows you to tweak the parameters by creating an `.l4j.ini` file with the same name as the exe. In case of Exe4J, extra parameters can be specified in a `.vmoptions` file which you drop next to the generated exe.
- Create a Shortcut to javaw.exe, give it the icon you want, set the "Start in" field to the directory of the application and specify your parameters to javaw in the Target field.
- Make a VB script which launches javaw. If the VBS runtime is set to use *wscript*, no console window will pop up.
- If you use Java Web Start, you might want to let the user tweak the JNLP file as specified in [Java Webstart with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199211/java-webstart-with-parameters).

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
start javaw -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -jar MyGUI.jar
```

You can also use [scripting](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/56092-hide-the-command-prompt-windows/):

VBS:

```
Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 12 

strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup") 

Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_ 
objConfig.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW 
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process") 
errReturn = objProcess.Create("Notepad.exe", null, objConfig, intProcessID)
```

JScript:

```
var WindowStyle_Hidden = 0
var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
var result = objShell.Run("cmd.exe /c abc.bat", WindowStyle_Hidden)
```

Finally, there are general-purpose utilities you can use to hide windows, such as [CMDOW](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/) and [Hidden Start ($20)](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html). I have not used either myself, since `start` does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

> The user wants to start the Java GUI application ..

The best user experience for the end user will be offered by launching the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS can install desktop shortcuts and menu items to launch the app.

> ..from Windows..

JWS also works on OS X & *nix.

Answer (score 2):

[Lauch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) can wrap your jar in an exe file.