# How can I run a Java from windows batch file but hiding the command window?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I have a `.bat` file include this command `java -jar example.jar` that runs `example.jar`.

I don't want `cmd.exe` to be visible on screen when the file is being executed. Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at [how-to-start-java-gui-program-conveniently-for-the-end-user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504943/how-to-start-java-gui-program-conveniently-for-the-end-user). It contains a simple answer to your question.

Answer (score 13):

Use javaw.exe rather than java.exe this should drop the shell

Comment: thank you guy,please help me about 'javaw.exe' whit an example.

Answer (score 8):

you can hide it like this:

```
start javaw -jar example.jar
```

Or if you call it from inside of another project you can call like like this:

```
try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /B example.bat");
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OpenFileFromCmd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OpenFileFromCmd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

If you have any question just ask me :))

Answer (score 5):

Start your bat file using the windows "start" command

```
Start "" /B "c:\myFolder\MyJavaLauncher.bat"
```

The "/B" option tell to start the program without showing the typical command window.

Answer (score 3):

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /B  example.bat");

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, your answer seems little...sparse. Could you please edit your answer and add an explanation as to _why_ to run this particular command?

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start /B" , "C:\\path\\urbatname.bat"};
        Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);           
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The /B allow you to execute the batch file invisibly. Just have the codes above in your function and it will work.