# Is there a way run a java class when I hit the submit button on my html form?

Tags: java, html

Is there a way to run a java class when I hit the submit button on an html form? I have this code for my html form: that gets the mean and the standard deviation as inputs.

```
<form action="Calculation.html" method="get">
    <input name="Mean" type="text" style="width:100%">
    <input name="Std" type="text" style="width:100%">
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

I would like to be able to run code from a java class that does some data analysis on the inputs of this form. But for now I am trying to get a HelloWorld.java class to run when I hit the submit button:

```
public class test{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Yes, there is a way but it requires a runtime container (such as jetty or tomcat) - those web application are called 'servlets' (basically applications that run on the server) - here's a primer on servlets: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97688_16/generic.903/a97681/servprim.htm

Comment: So to clarify things: Where do you want the Java code to run? Do you want it to run on the server, where your html comes from, or directly in the browser, where the html is rendered? If you want it to run in the browser, then why Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [Java Web Start](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml). That will let you start a Java application from a HTML page, although there are some security restrictions.

You can pass your inputs as arguments to the application as [discussed in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199211/java-webstart-with-parameters).